# Getting between the Parque Empresarial Torneo business district of Seville/Sevilla and the airport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, spain, seville

For an upcoming trip to Seville / Sevilla in Spain, I've noticed that you can get some very good rates on the weekend at some nice hotels in the Pino Montano / Parque Empresarial Torneo area of the city. This is a business and industrial area to the north of the city centre, so it seems to make sense that they'd be doing good deals on a weekend when there are fewer/no business travellers about.

My issue is if I did opt for a hotel there, rather than in the city centre, how to get to the airport on the Monday morning. The distance is just under 10km, but the website for the hotel I was looking at suggests it's about €30 for a taxi to/from the airport. For that taxi price, I'd be better off booking something a little more expensive per night in the city, and then taking the [airport bus](http://www.tussam.es/index.php?id=3&linea=2&no_cache=1) for €4.

The website of the [public transport provider for Sevilla, Tussam](http://www.tussam.es/) doesn't have its own trip planner, but instead sends you off to Google. That suggests that the only way to get to the airport from Pino Montano is to take a bus all the way into the city centre, change, then head out to the north west, taking about 90 minutes. Given that I could almost walk it in that time, it seems a fairly inefficient way to go!

Are there an public transport options that bypass the city centre? For example, any buses heading along Ronda Supernote to the airport, or along Ronda Urbana Nte to meet the airport bus at the Avenida de Kansas City Ibis stop? Are there cheaper taxi options than the €30 suggested by the hotel? Or should I just skip the nice hotel out there, and stay in the city centre within easy walk of the airport bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle the taxis in Sevilla are not too expensive. However, there is a [flat rate for transfers from the airport to the city](http://www.aena-aeropuertos.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Sevilla/en/Page/1237554620989//Taxi.html). The rates varies from 21.89 EUR to 30.50 EUR according to the period of travel. You are strongly penalised by the application of this flat rate: it more or less doubles the fare in your situation!

The only public transport option to get from the airport into Sevilla is the [line EA](http://www.aena-aeropuertos.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Sevilla/en/Page/1237554620981//Public-transport.html).

As an intermediate solution you might consider to take the bus EA to the Santa Justa train station and proceed from there by taxi, for 10 EUR or less.

You should be able to answer your last question by yourself.

> Or should I just skip the nice hotel out there, and stay in the city
>   centre within easy walk of the airport bus?

I would stay somewhere in the center. That way you minimze the travel and transfer times and you will get the most out of your weekend. You should not only factor in the price difference for the airport transfers, but also the daily public transport between the hotel and the sights, as well as the time loss.

Remark 1: there is a nice hotel (of a Spanish chain) at Plaza de Armas. It's next to the terminal of the EA bus line and only a stone's throw from the city center.

Remark 2: If you want to spend a weekend in a nice hotel with nice amenities, there are other better suited destinations for that!